# Insufficient permissions for local file change in strapi docker

Tags: docker, strapi

I tried to install strapi with PostgreSQL from its [official doc](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/installation/docker.html), I changed the name for mounted volumes in YAML file and keep all the rest the same as the given one in the doc.

based on strapi PostgreSQL docker-compose.yaml file [see original](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/installation/docker.html#step-1-create-a-docker-compose-yaml-file)

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  strapi:
    image: strapi/strapi
    # totally the same as doc
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/srv/app
    # totally the same as doc

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    # totally the same as doc
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Then I pulled the latest image, and run them all, and it worked.
The folder structure now has all needed files and all functionalities are working in GUI provided in `http://localhost:1337/admin/` and I could make the first content type.

```
\backend
  \\ all_strapi_files + node_modules
\database
docker-compose.yaml
```

But the problem is that I can't add additional changes to files inside my editor(vscode).

I face the following error on every try for saving file changes

```
Failed to save 'files': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser.
```

Also, I can not set up the yarn workspace properly, cause it doesn't have an access to remove `backend/node_modules`.
Git commands are not permitted either

```
 git clean -f -- something

> failed to remove something: Permission denied
```

I can save every file by `sudo` which vscode provides, but I guess I ruined something or there is some extra thing to setup. I'm not an expert in docker and strapi, so sorry for not mentioning all content that might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This docker-compose configuration isn't good when you have changed inside a container with mount bind. Scenarios like that it's better to use [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes).

```
[...]
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

 volumes:
  db-data:
```

How are you change Strapi with VSCode? My question is because most container images are configured to run with the root user, if possible when you are development to change outside the container and copy it to inside.

Comment: Hey, I want the same result as when installing the strapi with npx. it gives you the option to use the GUI or code itself to update your content types, and so on.